# class attribute set/get logic

Tags: ruby, attributes, logic

How would I accomplish the following?

```
class Monkey
    attr_setter(:name, new_name) 
        if is_supported(@version)
            @name = new_name
        else
            raise ":name is not supported for #{@version.to_s}"
        end
    end
    attr_getter(:name)
        if is_supported(@version)
            return @name
        else
            raise ":name is not supported for #{@version.to_s}"
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Monkey
    attr_reader :name 

    def name=(new_name)
        if is_supported(@version)
            @name = new_name
        else
            raise ":name is not supported for #{@version.to_s}"
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What about the attribute reader?  Can I do something similar there to raise an exception if someone accesses the property and the version isn't supported?

Comment: sure, you just end up over riding it so there is no need to do attr_reader just make a new "def name"